# Read data from more than one table using Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have 3 tables:

Table : Man

```
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "secondName")]
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
```

Table : Car

```
 public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string CarName { get; set; }
```

Table: ManCar

```
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "manId")]
    public string ManId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "carId")]
    public string CarId { get; set; }
```

C# reading date from Azure code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<String>> GetAllCarsByMan(Man man)
    {
         MobileServiceCollection<ManCar, ManCar> data;
         IMobileServiceTable<ManCar> dataTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<ManCar>();
        try
        {
            data = await dataTable
                .Where(item => item.ManId == man.Id).Select(menuItem => menuItem.CarId)
                .ToCollectionAsync();
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            Tools.errorList.AddMessage("AzureDataProvider.LoadData" + ex.ToString());
        }

        return data;
    }


public async Task<IEnumerable<Car>> GetAllCarsForAllMen()
    {   
         List<Car> listOfCars = new List<Car>();
         MobileServiceCollection<Man, Man> data;
         IMobileServiceTable<Man> dataTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<Man>();
     try
        {
            data = await dataTable.Where.ToCollectionAsync();

            foreach (var man in data)
            {
              var cars = await GetAllCarsByMan(Man man);

                if (cars.Count>0)
                { 
                 IMobileServiceTable<Car> dataCar = App.MobileService.GetTable<Car>();
                    foreach (var car in cars)
                    {
                      data = await dataTable.Where(item => item.Id == car).ToCollectionAsync();
                      if(data[0]!=null)
                      {
                        listOfCars.Add(data[0]);
                      }
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            Tools.errorList.AddMessage("AzureDataProvider.LoadData" + ex.ToString());
        }

        return listOfCars;
    }

public async Task<IEnumerable<String>> GetAllCarsByMan(Man man)
    {
         MobileServiceCollection<ManCar, ManCar> data;
         IMobileServiceTable<ManCar> dataTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<ManCar>();
        try
        {
            data = await dataTable
                .Where(item => item.ManId == man.Id).Select(menuItem => menuItem.CarId)
                .ToCollectionAsync();
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            Tools.errorList.AddMessage("AzureDataProvider.LoadData" + ex.ToString());
        }

        return data;
    }
```

When I try to get data from those tablets it's quite slowly. How can I read from this tables using AzureMobileServices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your code shows, you may possibly know about how to use LINQ queries.
The way you are using the code to access your db is super slow (e.g. it will result in one query run and LINQ overhead for each man cars)
It's best to write an API (CustomController) for your service and use LINQ join statements to retrieve your data (Single actual query to be run).
Search for Azure Custom API and LINQ join statements for more info